# How to modify map in go

Tags: dictionary, go

I am trying to modify the IPAddr for the "loopback", but it seems cannot access the element directly.

```
addrs["loopback"][0] = byte(2) //cannot assign to addrs["loopback"][0]
```

How can I do it within go?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type IPAddr [4]byte

func main() {
    addrs := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    addrs["loopback"][0] = byte(2)
    for n, a := range addrs {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", n, a)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because map values are not addressable, you need to reassign the entire value:

```
addr := addrs["loopback"]
addr[0] = 2
addrs["loopback"] = addr
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/ibrX594PC5)

If you change the map value type to *IPAddr, then the assignment

```
addrs["loopback"][0] = 2
```

works. In this case, the code is assigning to a value pointed to by the map. This value is addressable.

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/RO0fL-5DQZ)

Comment: I am wondering why it's immutable. the map should be similar as dic in Python, which can be modified directly.

Comment: It's not a good comparison  because Python does not have a type a type like Go's array type. If Python did have a type like Go's array type, I would think that the same rule applies. Map implementers what the freedom to move values around in memory.. The map value is mutable, it's just not addressable.

Comment: Another way to achieve it is to define IPAddr as a slice: type IPAddr []byte